# IBM WebSphere Application Server - Custom Admin UI - Querying WAS state

Tags: websphere

My goal is to build a custom application which serves a web page that shows information about multiple WAS instances. An example requirement is to list the deployed applications with each WAS instance. My preference is to build this application in Node.js. My challenge is how to inspect/query the WAS instances to retrieve the information that I will display on the web page. Technical options appear to be:

1. Write a java application which uses [WebSphere Admin Thin Client jar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_adminclient.html). This could run anywhere (not needed on all the WAS servers), then get Node.js to talk to this application.
2. Use the command line / shell tool [WSAdmin scripting tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_commandline.html), and interface to that from Node.
3. From node perform headless browsing of the [WebSphere Application Server Administration Console](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.install.doc/tasks/tig_start_was_admin_console.htm), and retrieve the data I am after.

Is there another/better way, ideally I was hoping for a HTTP REST or SOAP Admin API, that I could invoke from anywhere and point at the WAS instance to get the data I am after.

Comment: Sounds like this is pretty much re-writing the Administrative Console right?  It is already capable of listing deployed applications across multiple systems and JVMS (i.e. Cluster).  In any case, it's worth pointing out that the Administrative Console gets all of its data from the WSAdmin scripting tool, so that would be your one and only point to get data

Comment: Yes, you are right, pretty much re-writing parts of the Admin console. I need to show things from multiple consoles on one screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both shell wsadmin script and Web Administrative Console are connecting to DMGR by API ( SOAP or RMI).

If you are building your own Node.js app, maybe you will do a native connection to DMGR via JMX

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cjmx_overview.html